# Collabrative Embedded C programming projects

Tags: c, embedded

Looking for embedded C projects where I can work with group or individuals. My goal is to keep skills current while honing and learning new skills and techniques.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/), it seems to have a big community worldwide.